# Can I use the power rule to integrate a square root in the denominator?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int { \frac { dx }{ \sqrt { 3-4{ x }^{ 2 } }  }  } $$

Can I use the power rule to integrate this integral if first I transform the $ \sqrt{(3-4x^2)}$ to $(3-4x^2)^{-1/2}$$?$ Which techniques can I use?

Comment: Better to use trig substitution in your case.

Comment: You can write the function that way, but it probably won't be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Can I use the power rule to integrate this integral if first I transform the $1/ \sqrt{(3-4x^2)}$ to $(3-4x^2)^{-1/2}$*?

You *can't* obtain in general the antiderivative of
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{u}}
$$ *you need a differential element*
$$
\frac{u'}{\sqrt{u}}
$$ here
$$
(3-4x^2)'=-4x\ne1.
$$ Another route is better.

Comment: why a down vote here?

Comment: @oliver what do you mean by you need a differential element?

Comment: I mean that with a function $u$ we have $(u^n)'=nu'u^{n-1}$ and $u'$ is the differential element here.

Comment: @OlivierOloa so what technique should I use ?

Comment: You may find a change of variable to arrive at the integral $$\int \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin t +C$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa still confused... Even if I take out the 3. 1/sqrt(3(1-((4x^2)/3))) I still have the extra divided by 3

Answer (score 2):

This is a very natural question. The short answer is **no**.

But there is a better answer to give you, which is that you are capable of checking your antiderivatives. Namely, if you believe that
$$ \int (3 - 4x^2)^{-1/2} dx \stackrel{?}{=} 2(3 - 4x^2)^{1/2},$$
then you can check this by verifying that
$$ \frac{d}{dx} 2 (3 - 4x^2)^{1/2} = (3 - 4x^2)^{-1/2}.$$
(Or if you think the antiderivative is a little bit different, you can check that one instead). Perfoming that check here, you will see that this relationship does not hold.

Comment: Why two downvotes here? (+1)

Comment: @mixedmath I thought that also... that's why I ask this question... Anyway what technique should I use?